# How to extract date from a string in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, string, date

I've been wanting to extract a date in this specific format. **month/day/year**

`string inputText = "Examination held on January 06, 2015 at the University of Bikini Bottom";`

I've been thinking about Regex but I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: Regex wont work here, you will need to write a parser, first you will need to look for  one of the twelve month, once you find that in a sting, then you will have to grab the digits after which would be your day and after comma a year.  Its actually not that hard to do it.

Comment: can you specify all possible formats?

Comment: @FilixMogilevsky Well, you _could_ do that with a RegEx too but it would be fairly large.

Comment: "I've been thinking about Regex" which part of that are you stuck on?  Creating the regex or applying it to your string?

Comment: That's true actually, you could do anything with Regex, but the solution would be far more difficult then with C#.  I was half right :)

Answer (score 1):

The following Regex will work for the format in your example, as long as you are not too fussed on validating the date at the extraction stage:

```
string str = "Examination held on January 06, 2015 at the University of Bikini Bottom";
string regex = @"(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) *(\d|[0-3]\d), *\d{4}";
var result = Regex.Match(str, regex).Value; // January 06, 2015
```

Answer (score 1):

for this specific format you can use something like this:

```
string inputText = "Examination held on January 06, 2015 at the University of Bikini Bottom";
Regex r = new Regex(@"on (\w+ \d+, \d+)");

Console.WriteLine(r.Match(inputText).Groups[1].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to do two things

- extract the date sub string
- parse it

Is the string always "Examination held on <date> at the"? I hope so

```
var first = str.Substring(20); // 20 is the length of Examination held on 
var idx = first.IndexOf("at the");
var dt = first.Substring(0, idx);
```

now dt has the date string

Use DateTime.Parse to parse the date - google it